# JSF2.1.7 renders <!--[if IE ]> tag as text

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, facelets, conditional-comments

We upgraded our JSF to latest version 2.1. previously we were in JSF2.0.4. Our xhtml pages has Targeting IE Using Conditional Comments  tag,which were not rendered as text.

But with new JSF2.1.7 this is being rendered as text in IE . Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<h:outputText escape="false">` instead.

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if IE]&gt;&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;ie.css&quot;/&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Comment: Sorry, can't answer that from top of head right now. We always use `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS`. The symptoms at least indicate that rendering of comments has been changed to not interpret any enclosed HTML/JSF code inside comments anymore (which makes sense, of course).

Comment: Ugly solution but looks like it's the only possible way.

Comment: Since shortly, [OmniFaces](http://code.google.com/p/omnifaces/) provides a `<o:conditionalComment>` component for the purpose which is less ugly. See also the showcase: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<f:verbatim>
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="js/conditional-comment.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</f:verbatim>
```

Comment: The `<f:verbatim>` is deprecated since JSF 2.0.