# JSF 2.1 & IE Conditional Comments

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, conditional-comments

I've noticed that in JSF 2.1.* my IE conditional comments are no longer working.  Various characters are being replaced by HTML entities & invalidating the comment syntax.  BalusC has pointed out [a solution to the problem in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195310/jsf2-1-7-renders-if-ie-tag-as-text) which uses h:outputText.  My problem is that I want my conditional comments at the top of my page, around the first element.  This means that I can't use h:outputText as I haven't defined it's namespace yet.  I believe that's correct anyway.  Here's a code example.

Most by JSF pages nowadays will start off with a template similar to the HTML5 Boilerplate syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 my-application" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 my-application" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 my-application" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js my-application" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<h:head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ...
```

With BalusC's mentioned solution, I'd want `<h:outputText />` on line 2 but the h namespace isn't defined yet.  Is that an element I can use that I can attach the various namespaces to but won't affect my final HTML?  Any other ideas how I can get round this issue?

Lee,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap it all in a `<f:view>` and define the namespaces there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ...>
    ...
</f:view>
```

The entire JSF view is otherwise already implicitly wrapped in a `<f:view>`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC :)  I did wonder about f:view but decided to post here instead of trying it myself!

Comment: Do you still need to use `<h:outputText />` with this solution? Or does the `<f:view />` replace it?

Comment: Mowgli, you do still need the <h:outputText/> tag.  What this solution does is provide the namespace necessary to recognize the tag.