# JSF 2 how to set html style depending on browser version

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, conditional-comments, omnifaces

What i want to do in my JSF 2 application is to set proper html style depending on browser version, here is sample code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <!--<![endif]-->
```

How to do that in JSF 2? What is the best/simplest way?

I found something interesting in Omnifaces (`o:conditionalComment`) but it only allows conditional loading of entire css which is useless for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not true that the [`<o:conditionalComment>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment) is for CSS files *only*. That's a misconception. It's technically simply not possible to achieve your requirement with pure Facelets tags/components as it would result in malformed XML syntax and thus a Facelets compile error.

```html
<o:conditionalComment if="lt IE 7">
    <html lang="en" class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7">
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="IE 7">
    <html lang="en" class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8">
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="IE 8">
    <html lang="en" class="lt-ie9">
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="gt IE 8">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;!--&gt;" escape="false" />
    <html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;!--" escape="false" />
</o:conditionalComment>
...
</html>
```

This is **not** [well formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) XML. You know, the XML end element should be in the very same scope as XML start element. It would be valid XML if every `<html>` has its own `</html>` in the same parent XML element. But this is in turn not valid HTML.

Just use `<h:outputText escape="false">` on all `<html>` tags. Don't forget to do the same for the closing `</html>` tag.

```html
<o:conditionalComment if="lt IE 7">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; class=&quot;lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7&quot;&gt;" escape="false" />
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="IE 7">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; class=&quot;lt-ie9 lt-ie8&quot;&gt;" escape="false" />
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="IE 8">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; class=&quot;lt-ie9&quot;&gt;" escape="false" />
</o:conditionalComment>
<o:conditionalComment if="gt IE 8">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;!--&gt;&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot; class=&quot;no-js&quot;&gt;&lt;!--" escape="false" />
</o:conditionalComment>
...
<h:outputText value="&lt;/html&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Pretty awkward, but the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (where this approach originated) is at its whole own also awkward, IMO.

Alternatively, you could consider creating a custom `<my:html>` component yourself which generates the desired markup so that you can just suffice with `<my:html>...</my:html>`.

Comment: Thanks, for now I used single h:outputText. I also wrapped everything in f:view (namespace definitions). I used o:conditionalComment for js including. Its strange but the closing </html> <h:outputText value="&lt;/html&gt;" escape="false" /> was not needed, everything is rendered correctly, why? :)

Comment: I just wanted to throw in a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616944/jsf-2-1-ie-conditional-comments) to another question, where BalusC spells out the f:view thing in detail. I was trying to solve the same problem, and had a hard time finding all of the pieces of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

you can make 3 CSS (one per browser) with the same class. Your HTML code will be more simple.

In the header, you can use specific browser css like that:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="ie_7.css" rendered="#{header['User-Agent'].contains('; MSIE 7')}" />
```

Comment: Header sniffing is technically less reliable than conditional comments. Conditional comments work for 100% sure in IE, while request headers can be spoofed/hacked by the client.

Comment: Yes you're right, i learn something! Link about BalusC comment : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should not conditionally declare `<html>` elements.

What if somebody who is using Chrome, or Firefox wants to visit your site?

The accepted practice is to create IE version specific `.css` file and load this files conditionally using IE macros.

e.g

```
<link href="global_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if IE 7]-->
<link href="IE7_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]-->
<link href="IE6_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

In IE6_styles.css, you may add some specific attributes to `html` class, and maybe `* html` hack.  The beauty of this approach, is that it will function in old IE browsers, but will not break the modern ones.

BTW, this example is from "CSS: the missing manual" by David McFarland.

Comment: OP's snippet is coming from html5boilerplate.com.

Comment: Creating a bunch of .css files is what I do not want to do because what I got is one large css. If there is no choice then I got a lot of work preparing specific css files.