# How to declare XML namespaces when using conditional <html> tags

Tags: jsf, facelets, conditional-comments, omnifaces

I'm trying to implement this using JSF:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

I've found examples using omnifaces o:conditionalComment tag - but my problem is that the declaration of omnifaces is part of the html declaration.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions" >
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721560/jsf-2-how-to-set-html-style-depending-on-browser-version)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the XML namespaces in a `<f:view>` around the whole thing.

```
<f:view xmlns...>
    <html>...</html>
</f:view>
```